# Mac App Store : Technical vs Ethical Submission Guidelines

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, mac-app-store

I have read lots of threads about Mac App Store Review Guidelines, but it treats much more of ethical questions (age rating, copyright, privacy, etc...) than of actual misconduct in code writing (storage, protection, etc...)

However, forums seems full of people who saw their Apps rejected for these reasons, would you know a link which compile all these classic coding mistakes?

Comment: Most of the UX things you get from Human Interface guidelines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Applications are rejected if bugs *are observed* (and it is surprising what seemingly obvious bugs get through sometimes...) or if they break one of Apple's many, often loosely defined and variously interpreted (by Apple), rules. Apple don't see your code as such and are not looking at the perceived quality of your code.

So there is no list of "classic coding mistakes" that are *specific* to the Mac App Store (though someone could write, or may have written, one and label it "MAS classic errors" - but they'd just be "classic errors").

Comment: This is correct. They don't read your code, they instead test your app. If they find a bug, then they'll reject, if the reviewer doesn't care and doesn't really test it thoroughly, then bugs will get through.